# Cannot resize boot disk in Google compute engine

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine

I am newbie to Google cloud engine and I facing an issue when trying to ssh my instance.

*“Could not update /home/Name/.ssh/authorized_keys due to Disk is too full”*

The disk has important files and I cannot risk losing them. I tried to increase the disk size from 10G to 250G but still have the issue. I have not done any disk repartitioning because my OS image, Ubuntu, supports automatic resizing.

I have not restarted the instance yet because when I press Stop, I receive this message: "Stop shuts down the instance. If the shutdown doesn't complete within 2 minutes, the instance is forced to halt. This can lead to file-system corruption. ".  I am not sure if it is normal to get this message?

Finally, I noticed there is an option called “reset”. Would it simply restart my instance? I am afraid it will erase everything on the disk.

p.s. there are some answers to full disk problem but they are not relevant anymore since this [Google announcement](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/03/introducing-Google-Cloud-Persistent-Disks-with-non-disruptive-online-resizing.html).

Comment: Is it a persistent disk ? Have you tried to create a snapshot of the disk ?

Comment: yes it is. I created a snapshot after changing the disk size

Comment: Create a new volume (bigger size) from snapshot to confirm you have all your data then you are free to replace current vol with this new vol

Comment: I did as you said. Now I am facing another problem and I still cannot ssh into the instance. The problem has something to do with not being able to login. I tried connecting to a serial console and it keeps rejecting the username/password. I hope there is a way to change the current username/password.

Comment: Once you have created a new larger volume from a snapshot and verified your data is intact you are free to kill the current instance and re-deploy using new volume so ignore failure to ssh into the "Disk is too full" deployment